# Giving integer values to QPushButton(s) to apply C++ logic on them in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a switch case with condition values from 0-8. Upon each value, I give it an x and y coordinate of a 3x3 array. Then the code operates logic on the 3x3 array to get the results.

I also have 9 buttons in my Qt Designer ui (arranged in a 3x3 matrix). I want each click of the nine buttons to get a corresponding integer value which will then pass through the switch case.

```
switch (square_number)
{
case 1:         
    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    break;

case 2:
    x = 0;
    y = 1;
    break;

case 3:
    x = 0;
    y = 2;
    break;
.
.
.
//and so on...
default:
    break;
}
```

I want the square_number to get the integer value corresponding to the push-button clicked.

**QSignalMapper** seems obsolete or weird at the very least. And I am not that familiar with **lambda expressions**. Is there a simple way of doing what I want to do?

Comment: You might store a mapping between your buttons (pointers) and the corresponding `square_number`. All buttons are connected to the same slot with the mentioned `switch` statement. In the slot you get the pointer of the button clicked and get the corresponding `square_number` from the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach and use dynamic property:

```
static constexpr auto IndexPropertyName = "index";

void MainWidnow::SetupPB(QPushButton* b, QPoint index)
{
   connect(b, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &MainWidnow::onSomeButtoPressed);
   p->setProperty(IndexPropertyName, index);
}

void MainWidnow::onSomeButtoPressed(bool checked)
{
   auto index = sender()->property(IndexPropertyName).toPoint();
   doSomethingOn(index);
}
```

[QObject Class | Qt Core 6.4.0](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#setProperty)

> #### bool QObject::setProperty(const char **name*, const [QVariant](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvariant.html) &*value*)
>
> Sets the value of the object's *name* property to *value*.
>
> If the property is defined in the class using [Q_PROPERTY](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#Q_PROPERTY) then true is returned on success and false otherwise. **If the property is not defined using [Q_PROPERTY](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#Q_PROPERTY), and therefore not listed in the meta-object, it is added as a dynamic property and false is returned.**